# How to get past the memory leak warning (creating a sigleton class that extends the AsyncTask)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-asynctask

I have created a UDP communication application and it is working very well (so far). To receive UDP packets I am using an `AsyncTask` extension class.

For the sake of clarity (and brevity) I have divided the code into separate kotlin files.

**MainActivity.kt** handles the UI stuff like button press and creating objects
**LongTask.kt** defines a `LongTask` class that extends the `AsyncTask` (UDP receiver code)

I create a instance of `LongTask` on a **button press event** using the following

```
task = object : LongTask("$idx"){
                override fun onProgressUpdate(vararg values: String?) {
                    super.onProgressUpdate(*values)
                    Log.d(TAG, "On UI thread")
                }
            }

task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, "")
```

However, the above lines of code are highlighted in yellow and keep warning of a possible memory leak.

How to write a leak proof code to get past this warning?

Comment: do you need to access activity's variables from `LongTask`?

Comment: @Choim I need to get received UDP data from the AsyncTask regularly and use it for some processing.

Comment: your task is anonymous class. So, it has reference to outer class(MainActivity). Therefore, if `LongTask` is not released, `MainActivity` would be leaked. Ignore warning with making sure you have to release task or Make `LongTask` be static class.

Comment: @Choim I want to make LongTask static and I looked into few answers over web but couldn't follow. Can you add that as an answer?

Comment: You might want to try doing this as a bound service instead that runs on it's own thread.  Your activity can bind to this service, and unbind to it when it's done allowing you a chance to clean up properly.  See https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
task = object : LongTask("$idx"){
    override fun onProgressUpdate(vararg values: String?) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(*values)
        Log.d(TAG, "On UI thread")
    }
}
```

This line will create an anonymous inner class which extends from `LongTask` class. An inner class have an implicit reference to their outer class, in this case `MainActivity` class.

If the activity is finished before the asynctask completed, then the activity will be leaked or not collected by GC because it's still referred by the asynctask.

**Solution:** To avoid that we should use `WeakReference` API. In addition, `LongTask` is a separate class so we need to define an interface to pass data back to the activity.

First, declare an interface

**OnProgressUpdateListener.kt**

```
interface OnProgressUpdateListener {
    fun onProgressUpdate(vararg values: String?)
}
```

Second, modify the asynctask class. Just focus on `OnProgressUpdateListener` part because I don't know what exactly your class look like.

**LongTask.kt**

```
class LongTask(val idx: String, listener: OnProgressUpdateListener) : AsyncTask<String, String, Unit>() {

    private val mListener: WeakReference<OnProgressUpdateListener>? = WeakReference(listener)

    override fun doInBackground(vararg params: String?) {

    }

    override fun onProgressUpdate(vararg values: String?) {
        mListener?.get()?.onProgressUpdate(*values)
    }
}
```

Finally, let the activity implements `OnProgressUpdateListener`.

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnProgressUpdateListener {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        task = LongTask("$idx", this)
        task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, "")
    }

    override fun onProgressUpdate(vararg values: String?) {
        // Update your progress on UI thread here
        Log.d(TAG, "On UI thread")
    }
}
```